# Need to read a file from cin

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a file and print out the size of it in bytes. I am able to print it out if I physically in the code give it the file name. But I want to be able to choose the file at run time from standard in. This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    FILE * file;
    float size;
    string myfile;
    file = fopen( "countChar.cpp", "rb" );
    if( file == NULL )
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    else{
        fseek( file, 0, SEEK_END );
        size = ftell(file);
        fclose(file);
        cout << "Size of " << myfile << " is  " << size << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to replace "countChar.cpp" with myfile and get my file from cin.
Thanks!

Comment: `ftell` returns `long int`, not `float`. Quit ignoring the warnings from your compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
int main(){
    FILE * file;
    float size;
    string myfile;
    cout << "Enter a filename: ";
    cin >> myfile;
    file = fopen(myfile.c_str(), "rb" );
```